# VBScript error 80004005 check class in IE Document

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to set my script to sleep until a class is available in a website.

```
Set IE = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
strURL = "SomeUrl"

If IsNull(IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("button")) Then
    IE.navigate strURL
    Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4)    
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop
End If
```

I've looked the error and it does not specify what is wrong so I have no idea.
"Unspecified Error" Code 80004005 at:

```
If IsNull(IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("button")) Then
```

I've also tried:

```
Set Button = IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("button")
If IsNull(Button) Then
    IE.navigate strURL
    Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4)    
        WScript.Sleep 100
    Loop
    Set Button = IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("buttonp")
End If
```

Same error. What's the problem?

Comment: You need to _navigate_ to a resource identified by a URL _successfully_ **before** you can get its `Document` property.

Comment: @JosefZ The Document loads later in the script. This is a loop. If the webpage doesn't display this Document, I want the next time this loop runs, to reload the webpage. That's why I want to check if it's not null.

Comment: @JosefZ To explain better, at this stage, the website is fully loaded but that button is dinamically loaded and sometimes it doesn't load. This script is supposed to detect if there is a button by the class name "button" and if it is not, I want to navigate to that strURL. Basically to refresh the webpage if there is no button.